# Apache Fuseki: invoke str function

Tags: sparql, linked-data, fuseki, apache-jena

I would run this query: 
`SELECT DISTINCT ?id str(?name)` 
but Fuseki give me this error: *This line is invalid.Expected ( VAR1...* 
I would need a string value of `?name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are talking about something like this.

[image: YASQE]

This message is a warning produced by Fuseki component called YASGUI (or rather YASQE).

You have two options:

- Use more [conformant](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rSelectClause) syntax, i. e. `SELECT DISTINCT ?id (str(?name) AS ?str_name)` etc.
- Ignore this warning and run your query, Jena ARQ should accept it and return a result.

Comment: Why should ARQ accept it? Jena ARQ follows the SPARQL spec and will lead to a syntax error. You can check always on http://sparql.org/query-validator.html which is backed by Apache Jena ARQ.

Comment: @AKSW, perhaps I'm misunderstanding Apache Jena Fuseki architecture, but just try to press the button in the top right corner (even if yellow exclamation mark is displayed).

Comment: @AKSW, probaly [1](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/ARQ.html#setStrictMode--) and [2](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/cc038809fb622779933831011909714e22ef494c/jena-cmds/src/main/java/arq/cmdline/CmdARQ.java#L54).

Comment: Fuseki runs with extended SPARQL syntax. There are not many extensions and they are mostly for legacy reasons and have been replaced by SPARQL 1.1 constructs.

Comment: @StanislavKralin,AndyS Oh, I didn't know - always thought that the whole Jena stack works on SPARQL 1.1 by default. Cheers