# Aggregate properties

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia, fuseki

I'm developing my own Fuseki endpoint from some DBpedia data.
I'm in doubt on how to aggregate properties related to a single resource.

```sql
SELECT ?name ?website ?abstract ?genre ?image
WHERE{
VALUES ?s {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!>}
  ?s  foaf:name ?name ;
      dbo:abstract ?abstract .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbo:genre ?genre } .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbp:website ?website } .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbo:image ?image } .
  FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract ), "en")
}
```

SPARQL endpoint: http://dbpedia.org/sparql/

This query returns 2 matching results. They are different just for the `dbo:genre` value. There is a way I can query the knowledge base and retrieving a single result with a list of `genres`?

Comment: The first triple pattern is unnecessary as it denotes a property RDF triple with no variables. Moreover, `VALUES` can be used to make the query more compact, see my edited query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@chrisis's query works well on the DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint, which is based on Virtuoso.

However, if you are using Jena Fuseki, you should use more conformant syntax:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT
?name
(SAMPLE(?website) AS ?sample_website)
(SAMPLE(?abstract) AS ?sample_abstract)
(SAMPLE(?image) AS ?sample_image)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?genre; separator=', ') AS ?genres)
WHERE {
  VALUES (?s) {(<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!>)}
  ?s  foaf:name ?name ;
      dbo:abstract ?abstract .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbo:genre ?genre } .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbp:website ?website } .
  OPTIONAL { ?s dbo:image ?image} .
  FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract ), "en")
} GROUP BY ?name
```

The differences from the @chrisis's query are:

- Since `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregation function, it might be used with `GROUP BY` only;
- Since  `GROUP BY` is used, all non-grouping variables should be aggregated (e.g. via `SAMPLE`);
- `GROUP_CONCAT` syntax is slightly different.

---

In Fuseki, these `AS` in the projection are in fact superfluous: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44832260/7879193) and comments.

Comment: The AS is not superfluous.  It's mandated by the spec. if you're trying to write a legal query, it should be included. Just because some endpoints might handle the illegal syntax isn't really a great reason to omit it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the GROUP_CONCAT() function is what you want.

```
SELECT ?name ?website ?abstract (GROUP_CONCAT(?genre,',') AS ?genres) ?image
WHERE{
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!> a dbo:Band ;
       foaf:name ?name;
      dbo:abstract ?abstract .
  OPTIONAL{   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!> dbo:genre ?genre } .
  OPTIONAL{   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!> dbp:website ?website} .
  OPTIONAL{   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Attack_Attack!> dbo:image ?image} .
FILTER LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract ), "en")

}
```